# Переменные zeroX, zeroY не сохраняют своих значений

Tags: unity3d

переменные zeroX, zeroY принимают определенные значения в функции Start(), больше они нигде не меняются. но при вызове функции clickButtonNum() их значения оказываются не теми, какие были получены в результате работы Start(), в чем может проблема?

```
public class UI_Game : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject button, imageParent;
GameObject[,] matrixButtons = new GameObject[4, 4];
int[,] modelMatrix = new int[4, 4];
private int zeroX;
private int zeroY;


void Start () // срабатывает при создании объекта
{
    generateMap (); 
}


private void generateMap() //генерирует поле для игры
{
    int[] num = new int[16];
    for (int a = 0; a != 16; a++) //массив с числами для создания модели поля
    {
        num [a] = a;
    }

    mixArray (num);

    int index = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x!=4;x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y != 4; y++) 
        {
            if (num [index] != 0) 
            {
                createButton (x,y,num [index]);
                modelMatrix [x, y] = num [index];           //запоминаем положение номеров кнопок в модель
            } 
            else 
            {
                modelMatrix [x, y] = num [index];
                zeroX = x;
                zeroY = y;
            }
            index++;
        }
    }

}


private void createButton(int x, int y, int num) // создает кнопку-фишку с нужным числом в нужных коорднатах
{
    GameObject buttonLink = Instantiate (button);
    buttonLink.transform.SetParent (imageParent.transform);                          
    Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3 (-60 + x * 40, -60 + y * 40);
    buttonLink.transform.localPosition = newPosition;
    buttonLink.transform.Find ("Text").GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text> ().text = num.ToString();
    buttonLink.transform.GetComponent<Coordinates_button> ().set_x (x);
    buttonLink.transform.GetComponent<Coordinates_button> ().set_y (y);
    matrixButtons [x, y] = buttonLink;
}


private void mixArray(int [] num) // перемешивает числа в массиве
{
    int swapNum = Random.Range (10, 20); 
    for (int a = 0; a != swapNum; a++) 
    {
        int firstNum = Random.Range (0, 16);
        int secondNum = Random.Range (0, 16);         
        int bufer = num [firstNum];
        num [firstNum] = num [secondNum];
        num [secondNum] = bufer;
    }
}


public void clickButtonNum()  // обратывает нажатие по кнопке-фишке
{
    Debug.Log (zeroX);
```

Comment: "значение оказывается ... не тем, что нужно" - какое нужно и какое оказывается - это мы должны угадать?

Comment: Числа. Числа какие там? и какие Вы ожидаете?

Comment: ну ожидаются рандомные числа от 0 до 3 включительно, например в zeroX записалось значение 1, когда я его использую, оно всегда 0, для zeroY всегда 3

Answer (score 0):

Скопировал ваш скрипт к себе. В Awake сгенерировал карту, в Start вывожу в консоль zeroX и zeroY - каждый раз они разные, а значит все работает правильно. Т.е. на момент создания они точно не всегда 0 и 3. Видимо, вы, всё же, где-то их потом ещё меняете. Выделите переменную и нажмите Shift+F12 - вам покажет все места, где она используется